# Rails how to sort by occurrences in HABTM table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

```
Questions:
    has_and_belongs_to_many :topics

Topics:
    has_and_belongs_to_many :questions
```

And the associated joining table: `questions_topics`

**How can I write a query to get all topics and their occurrences in the joining table, and sorted by the count (showing by order of the most active topics first)?**

So basically I want to be able to do this in a single query:

1. `list = Topics.all`
2. Order list by `list.questions.count`

**Update:**

**Is there a better rails way to write the following query?** (which does appear to give the required result:

`Topic.includes(:questions).group('questions_topics.topic_id').references(:questions).order("count(questions_topics.topic_id) DESC")`

Comment: You use Rails 3 or 4?

Comment: I would suggest using a "counter cache column" and use that for your queries. That is way more performant and rails takes care of counting.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Rails 4